# I'm using Parse Server with Heroku, and I'm having problems with PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-server

```
@IBAction func forgotPasswordTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let username = self.emailTextField.text {
        PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: username) { (success, error) in
            if(success) {
                print("forgot password successful and sent")
            }


        }
    }
}
```

When that function is called, I get the following error message

> "An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset and email verification functionality. (Code: 1, Version: 1.16.0)"

Is there something that I need to do with Heroku mail settings to enable it?  If yes, would you give me directions on how to do it?  I tried using the "mailgun" and "sendgrid" add on for Heroku, but didn't know how to configure it.

screenshot of my parse dashboard : https://www.evernote.com/l/Aq9A4JQSO_1L3rEmnFuZOyHsVvs7gY5Ttc8

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, make sure you have the mailgun adapter.

```
"dependencies": {
    "parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter": "*"
}
```

Then in your index.js or wherever you start the api.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    appName: 'App Name',
    appId: 'app Id',
    emailAdapter: {
        "module": "parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter",
        "options": {
            "fromAddress": "address@youremail.com",
            "domain": "your.mailgun.domain",
            "apiKey": "mailgun-api-key"
        }
    }
})
```

If this was helpful you should mark it as the accepted answer.